# Explain this recursive algorithm to print all the ordered numbers of a number of digits

Tags: java, math, recursion

I have this code to print all "ordered" numbers of a number of digits, given the number of digits

(If number is `xyz`, then it is ordered iff x<y<z),

The code works, but I am unable to understand the logic used in the for loop. It is recursion, but if anyone can explain more, that would be great.

```
class OrderedNumbers{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        printOrdered(0,0,3); // 3 digit numbers
    }

    private static void printOrdered(int number, int prev, int n) {

        if(n==0){
            System.out.println(number);
            return;
        }

        for(int i=(prev+1); i<(11-n); i++){
            printOrdered(number*10 + i, i, n-1) ;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming you didn't write this code (otherwise you would understand it), where did you find this code?

Comment: I found it on some website in the form of pseudocode. I don't recall the website. I was trying to understand it by running it and debugging, but could not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the arguments.

- `number` is the number composed so far. We multiply that by ten before we add the last digit, in order to append one more digit to that number.
- `prev` is the value of the previous digit. The `for` loop will start one after that, thus ensuring that the digits within the number are ordered.
- `n` is the number of digits yet to append. When that reaches zero, the maximal recursion depth has been reached and the number gets printed. We also use `n` in the computation of the upper limit in the `for` loop. The last digit may be no larger than 9, the second to last no larger than 8, and so on. YOu can see this from the fact that for `n=1` the condition reads `i<10`, i.e. `i<=9`.

The recursive call will pass the previous number with one more digit appended, the value of that digit to ensure that the following one is larger, and the number of remaining digits reduced by one.

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of the function controls how many times the function calls itself. When `printOrdered` calls itself in the loop it takes the current number and moves multiplies it by ten (shifts the digits to the left one place). It then adds `i` (puts it in the ones place). When `n=0` the function knows that all the necessary digits have been added and so it returns (prints) the current number.

`i` runs from one more than the previous digit (otherwise it would not be an ordered number) to `11-n`, this is saying that in a number with `n` digits, the most significant digit can only be as large as `11-n`. Consider the biggest ordered number with 3 digits `789`. The hundreds place can never be larger than 7, do you see why?

In summary

- `number` is the current (and possibly incomplete) ordered number
- `prev` is the last digit that was added to `number`
- `n` is the number of digits that need to be added to `number`
- `i` loops over all the digits that could be added to `number` in the next place. It has to be greater than the last digit but still leave room for the remaining digits that will be added once `printOrdered` is called again.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that for a number to be "ordered", the leftmost digit must less than `(11-n)`, where `n` is the number of digits. If you're working with 3 digits, "789" is ordered, but if the leftmost digit was 8, followed by 9, there would be no higher digit left to fill the rightmost position. (The same is true of all the other digits.)

In the first call to `printOrdered`, the `for` loop generates all the valid digits which can be used in the leftmost position. For each such digit, the recursive call generates all the valid digits which can be used in second-to-leftmost position, and so on. `number` is an accumulator which builds up the number to be printed, whereas `n` counts down until the number to be printed has been fully built up. `prev` is named misleadingly; it is the digit which will appear to the *left* of this one. For the number to be "ordered", you can only generate digits which are *higher* than `prev`, which is why the loop variable is initialized to `prev + 1`.